# A really closed polygon is not accepted by turf.polygon

Tags: javascript, mapbox-gl-js, turfjs

Defining a method:

```
drawFragment : function(pFRAGMENT) {
        console.log(pFRAGMENT.coordinates);
        var wPolygon = turf.polygon([pFRAGMENT.coordinates]);
},
```

results in a turf error in execution:

> *First and last Position are not equivalent.*

The passed coordinates are (first and last pair are identical - as required):

```
[[8.543590974130666, 47.377830192117756],
[8.543672439897477, 47.377850806388665],
[8.543667400529785, 47.37788614972462],
[8.543582309906242, 47.37791046432616],
[8.543590974130666, 47.377830192117756]]
```

What's wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

## See

```js
const data = turf.polygon(
  [
    [
      [8.543590974130666, 47.377830192117756],
      [8.543672439897477, 47.377850806388665],
      [8.543667400529785, 47.37788614972462],
      [8.543582309906242, 47.37791046432616],
      [8.543590974130666, 47.377830192117756],
    ],
  ],
  { name: 'poly1' }
);

console.log(data);
```

I didn't get any errors.
have a look https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-jzkxtn?file=index.js

Comment: Thanx. Your comma after the last pair is false.When I copy/paste the data into the method I don't get an error too.

Comment: My crosscheck is:

const wPolygonT = turf.polygon(
[
  [
      [8.543590974130666, 47.377830192117756],
      [8.543672439897477, 47.377850806388665],
      [8.543667400529785, 47.37788614972462],
      [8.543582309906242, 47.37791046432616],
      [8.543590974130666, 47.377830192117756]
    ]
 ]
    );
consol.log(wPolygonT);
----> everything fine.
But I have to PASS the data to the method.

The data are stored in the mariadb database exactly as shown in a varchar field